# Alternative of find command to use for powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Any alternative command to use this find and upload file to server using PowerShell

```
find <directory name>/ \! -type d -print0 | xargs -P10 -0 -I@ curl -v --user <user>:<password> --upload-file ./@ http://localhost:8081/repository/<repository name>/@
```